# Do I need to connect my Realm based database to a server before launch?

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform, realm

I have an iOS application that uses Realm as my relational database.  A few questions I have:

How is Realm server less?
How do I view the database (like Parse)?
Is all the data stored on your phone? If so, will it be deleted if a user deletes the app?
Can I trust Realm/what else do I need to do to make sure my app is scalable when it goes on the app store?

Answer (score 2):

Realm is just a database. It is stored on the device. If user deletes the app - the database will be gone, along with all other content of your app. There is no server-side to it.

Comment: How do I configure Realm to work with multiple users?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I sounds like you want a server that all your users can access, not a local database on the device.

Comment: Isn't Realm capable of handling multiple users on more than one device?